# How to stop Service from another activity in Android?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, unbind

I have 2 activities, A & B. The Service starts in B with such code:

```
 startService(new Intent(this, PlayerService.class));
             Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerService.class);
             bindService(connectionIntent, mp3PlayerServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

 private ServiceConnection mp3PlayerServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName arg0, IBinder binder) {
        mp3Service = ((LocalBinder) binder).getService();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        mp3Service.playSong(getApplicationContext(),url);
        }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
     }
 };
```

I need to have a possibility to close the service when I'm on activity A (B is closed, but music plays). How to call StopService from A onDestroy()? Need I to unbind it, if yes, how and where?

Simply putting `stopService(new Intent(this,PlayerService.class));` leads to an error: Activity B has leaked Service connection ... that was originally bound here. (But B is already closed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should unbind service in B onStop(), then you can call stopService in A.

Comment: startService in onCreate, bind in onStart and unbind in onStop.

Comment: Seems to be working, if only multiple runs of B and back to A can't cause some problems (for ex., connection wasn't made/off in time, some concurrent problems).

Comment: Set a flag in your service boolean mIsPlaying and check this flag in onServiceConnected. If mIsPlaying is true do nothing.

Comment: Sorry, the problem becomes annoying. I want to have the possibility of stopping Service only in A activity dialog, only when user wants to leave an app, confirming in a dialog, that music won't play in the background. So in this case I'll stop service. In other cases, for ex., coming to B 2-nd time, I got error: Activity B has leaked Service connection ... that was originally bound here.

Comment: Well, seems to be working again... there are a lot of cases of moving in app. Now moved bind to onStart, recalling the activity again doesn't cause such an error.

Comment: can you clarify what this flag is intended for?

Comment: If the music is playing you do not want to call mp3Service.playSong again. So either you set a flag in your B activity and not calling mp3Service.playSong when the flag is true. Or better you set a flag in your service mIsplaying and check in then playSong check if the flag is true then do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have in playSong method the check whether is current url equals previously started, if yes, then new player mustn't be created.

Comment: Then my solution should work. You should not unbind onDestroy() since if the user press the home button onDestroy() would not be called.

Answer (score 3):

So to clear some things up. Services can be of two types, not necessarily mutually exclusives.

These two types are started and bounded.

A STARTED service is one started with `startService()` and is usually used to accomplish background operations that are somewhat independent from the flow of the activity. For ex,ample a service to download remote data may run independently from the activity that created it and then simply return the result when ready.

A started service keeps running until it stops itself.

A BOUNDED service is more like a client-server IPC pattern. For example an audio media player should be a bound service in order for the activity to be able to query the service about the state of the media player, e.g. track name, lenght...

A Bound Service lives as long as there is a component bound to it.

So, if your service is started, you should stop it from inside your service implementation with `stopSelf()` or `stopService()`. If it is bound, it stops himself when there is no more components bound to it. You unbind a service with `unbindService()`. Note that a service can be both a started and a bound service!

For more information, refer to this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Consider also using an `IntentService` instead of a `Service` in your application, since it seems that you don't need your service to be multithread.

Answer (score 1):

you need to `Unbind` the `service` before destroying your `Activity`. `unbindService(myConnection);`

Comment: I.e. onDestroy() in B I must put Unbind?

Answer (score 1):

Try    `unbindService()` in your `onStop()`